# Get current position of a mobile every 2 minutes android

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I have an app which has three doinbackground async functions one after the other. The first function gets the latitude and longitude of the current position of the mobile using opencell api by passing mcc,mnc,cellid and lac. On post execute of this function calls another api to get the current time of the location based on latitude and longitude.After execution of this function, I am calling a server page to save all these gathered data to mysql db.

I want to do the same process to be repeated every one minute.How can we achieve it?Right now, this works as an app and every time I start the app, the data is saved to mysql.

Comment: Use Alarm Manager to to kick your GPS. Then do your typical routine.

Comment: Take a look at fused location api's. It gives you the latitude, longitude, date at regular intervals and it is simple to implement (if it isn't compulsory to implement opencell  api).

Comment: @srikar can you please give some example? Its not must to use opencell. I  just figured that would be the way to do it.I cant use the GPS though. I have to get the location based on the SIM card.Can I use fused location api for this??

Comment: @Enzokie,I cant use GPS,need to get location via sim .Can you give some simple example using alarm manager

Answer (score 0):

```
 public  void StartAlaramServiceforDataService(){

    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
    calendar.add(Calendar.SECOND, 1);
    Intent intentToQB = new Intent(SendLatlong.this, LocationFetchService.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(getApplicationContext(),1212, intentToQB, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,calendar.getTimeInMillis(),60*1000, pendingIntent);//You can change Time here


}
```

In LocationFetchService Get LatLong

Answer (score 0):

Don't use Async task like this for getting location in every 2 minutes there is perfect solution that is "Fused Location Provider". it gives us device location on a regular interval you can set it for 2 minutes tale a look on this https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-location/tree/master/LocationUpdates

Comment: The link says To run this sample, location must be enabled.However I am not supposed to use GPS to do this task.

Comment: This sample might use the necessity for this but fused location provider use three modes gps,wifi and network provider so you get location in regular interval.you can get the location without it but for better results you must use gps.

Comment: Thank you I will try and get back